# I have a problem while using update query

Tags: mysql

I have two tables x and y contains two columns each say (email and password) in my database.

I am not able understand how to update password in a table using where (email=...) clause so that if email belongs to x table then it's password get updated or if email belongs to y table then it's password get updated.

I tried in this way where the given email belongs to x table so that first query executed .

```
UPDATE x SET password="qas" where email="adsf@gmail.com";
UPDATE y SET password="qas" where email="adsf@gmail.com";
```

I am able to update separate (two) queries but i want single query which checks email in both tables and get password updated.

Comment: 'i want single query' - not possible - you could make life difficult for yourself by puttng the process into a stored procedure and testing for existence in x or y. Or fix your db so that you have only 1 table.

Comment: You are storing the same kind of informations in 2 separate tables, this smells poorly designed DB. [DRY !](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). [Database Normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: can you combine the two tables ?

Answer (score 0):

If the 2 tables are relatable then you can update using join:

```
UPDATE x 
JOIN y ON x.email = y.email
SET x.password = "qas", y.password = "qas" 
where x.email="adsf@gmail.com";
```

If the 2 tables are not relatable then you cannot update in a single query

Comment: This is will not work when email not exist in one of tables

Answer (score 0):

The below query will work in your case:

```
update X
join Y
set 
    X.password = if(X.email = 'adsf@gmail.com', 'qas' , X.password),
    Y.password = if(Y.email = 'adsf@gmail.com', 'qas' , Y.password)
where 
    X.email = 'adsf@gmail.com' or
    Y.email = 'adsf@gmail.com'
;
```

But I'm not sure about query performance

[Live fiddle here](https://phpize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=f0edd002b569850b5de074587a61dbbe&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql80)